# how to use facebook credentials to log in to my native mobile web application

Tags: html, facebook, sqlite, authentication

im doing a web base mobile using jquery and html and using sqlite database for log in. right now im struggling with sqlite database log in so im thinking of an alternative like using facebook credentials as a means to log in in my native app is this feasible if yes can anyone point me to right track?can someone give sample code im new in this so sample code with be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are searching for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Samplecode will need more specification since you need to know if you will use a js-libary or for example go through the process manually.

If you need help on a specific problem feel free to ask with more specifications.